# Using fork to create a child print a-z & parent process A-Z in c++

Tags: c++, process, parallel-processing, operating-system, fork

I am trying to use fork() to create a child process that will print out letters from a to z in small letters and parent process that will print out the alphabet in capital letters.

```
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Program Begins" << endl;

char letter;
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0)
{
    // child process
    for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
    {
        cout<< "child process: " << letter << endl;
    }
}

else if (pid > 0)
{
    // parent process
    for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)
    {
        cout << "parent process: " << letter << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    // fork failed
    cout << "fork failed" << endl;
    return 1;
}

cout << "End of Program\n" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

This code prints out the letters the problem is it does all of child first and then the parent. I thought it would create the two processes at the same time that will be running parallel to each other so then it will print out some a mixed result where some of them would be for the process while others for the parent process and so on. My question is I think the program is stuck in the loop once it looks at the process type and enters the loop for that process and doesnt exit until it prints out everything

Comment: You can't guarantee much about how the OS will schedule your threads or processes. Try sleeping for a brief period of time in each loop iteration.

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: It is possible that one finishes this short loop before it gets preempted by the OS so that the other one is started. If you use longer loops or add a delay between loop iterations, you will eventually see that the two run in parallel.

Comment: `std::thread ` gives you more control over _parallel processing_.

Answer (score 3):

Multithreaded/Multiprocess programs are inherently nondeterministic. The OS decides when each task has been active for too long and when it's time to schedule a new task, and because of that, especially because your program is pretty short, there's a good chance that the child will finish executing before the parent gets a chance to be placed active again, or vise-versa.

If you're expecting the program to interleave the two processes, you could add a sleep statement inside the loop to slow it down and force the CPU to flip more regularly.

If you're actually expecting the program to precisely and evenly alternate between the two, then you either need to use Mutexes or remove the multithreading.

Answer (score -1):

using fork() Create a child process and parent process and Child process should print no. from 10 to 1 and Parent process should print factorial of a no.